# iOS - How to get amount of notifications in notification center of my application

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am facing a issue. I need to know how many notifications of my app in notification center to resolve it. I have searched around but still cannot find a way to do this. Please help me. Thank so much.

P/s: I am using swift 2

Comment: are you keeping track of how many notifications you are sending from your server?

Comment: @MaxNelson yes, something like that. Actually, I just want to know how many notification of my app that are showing in notification center when I open my application